# arm64 support not provided in mkimage

Tags: linux, u-boot

I am trying to create an u-boot supported image using `mkimage`, when I try using:

```
mkimage -A arm64
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid CPU Type - valid names are: alpha, arm, x86, ia64, m68k, microblaze, 
                   mips, mips64, nios2, powerpc, ppc, s390, sh, sparc, sparc64,
                   blackfin, avr32, nds32, or1k, sandbox
```

So I see there is no support for arm64.

I tried compiling a new version of u-boot, but the `mkimage` in u-boot is also not supporting arm64.

I tried installing u-boot-tools on my ubuntu pc with:

```
sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools
```

But this `mkimage` also is giving me the same problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Just curious, which versions of Ubuntu, u-boot and mkimage are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As a valid architecture for mkimage, arm64 has been valid since roughly v2014.01-rc2 (and v2014.04 was the first full release with aarch64 support).  That said, for most cases you either want to use **booti** which will boot the 'Image' format that the Linux Kernel generates for arm64 (similar to using **bootz** on arm32) or to generate a [FIT image](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/uImage.FIT/howto.txt;h=14e316f72c1eced4c033c8f59718b31fc3138577;hb=HEAD) instead.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i compiled 2016 u-boot and mkimage from uboot tools is supporting arm64